# How do QCompleter and QAbstractItemModel work in PySide?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, qcompleter

I'm seeing a weird behavior in PySide when I use my own [QCompleter](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCompleter.html) and [QAbstractItemModel](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html) together, and I can't find documentation in PySide (or Qt for that matter) which explains what it's doing.

When I have an edit box using the QCompleter, and I type in additional characters, there is a huge number of calls to [`QAbstractItemModel.data()`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.data) to get the completion column content of a whole lot of items. This call occurs for the items that are relevant, several times for each item, but also for each of the top-level items immediately below the root.

Since my data model has hundreds (and potentially thousands) of top-level items in it, I am a little concerned I'm doing something wrong. I just want to make sure it doesn't bog down my computer doing irrelevant computations.

I created an example here: https://gist.github.com/jason-s/6c9495e29a4caac7ddf5cd739550a310
which I based off of [my earlier example in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718460/44330)

If I run it as `python qtcompleter5.py -e 25` and I type `United States/Arizona/P` into the edit box, what I see in my console is shown below. (The `Miragi012stan` entries are intentional, to easily vary the top-level item count by varying the `-e` argument.)

```
splitPath:  [u'United States', u'Arizona', u'P']
Canada
France
Germany
United States
Mexico
Miragi000stan
Miragi001stan
Miragi002stan
Miragi003stan
Miragi004stan
Miragi005stan
Miragi006stan
Miragi007stan
Miragi008stan
Miragi009stan
Miragi010stan
Miragi011stan
Miragi012stan
Miragi013stan
Miragi014stan
Miragi015stan
Miragi016stan
Miragi017stan
Miragi018stan
Miragi019stan
Miragi020stan
Miragi021stan
Miragi022stan
Miragi023stan
Miragi024stan
Peoria
Peoria
Phoenix
Peoria
Peoria
Peoria
Peoria
Phoenix
Phoenix
```

which seems to me like `.data()` is being called for all the top level items, and then 3-6 times for the actual items that might match the text in the completion window.

The only time it doesn't do this is when I'm typing in the top-level item, e.g. `Unite` which produces these calls:

```
splitPath:  [u'Unite']
United States
United States
United States
splitPath:  [u'Unite']
United States
United States
United States
United States
United States
```

(By the way, I can comment out the TreeView stuff, leaving only the QLineEdit, so the TreeView isn't the part causing the problem.)

The same behavior (querying of all top-level items) happens even if I try to help by telling PySide I'm using sorted models (see [qtcompleter5a.py](https://gist.github.com/jason-s/6c9495e29a4caac7ddf5cd739550a310#file-qtcompleter5a-py)) by using [`completer.setModelSorting(QtGui.QCompleter.CaseInsensitivelySortedModel)`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCompleter.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QCompleter.setModelSorting)

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't know if this is a good idea, but if I put all the top-level nodes under a dummy node, then only the dummy node gets a "useless" query during completion.

See https://gist.github.com/jason-s/6c9495e29a4caac7ddf5cd739550a310#file-qtcompleter5b-py

Changes I made from qtcompleter5.py:

- Header item is a separate item, not used as the root
- Dummy node returns `""` for the contents of the completion column in the `DisplayRole`
- Paths returned by QCompleter.splitPath have an extra dummy component in front
- The first component of `pathFromIndex()` is ignored if it's a root node
- In the AbstractItemModel:

  - `rowCount()` returns 1 for an invalid parent
  - `parent()` returns the invalid `QtCore.QModelIndex()` when the provided index is at the root (previously it was when the index's parent was at the root)
  - `index()` returns the root item when the provided parent is invalid (previously it looked up an appropriate child item of the root item)

This makes a TreeView of this model a bit funny-looking, but for applications that don't need the TreeView, it seems to work ok; if I enter `United States/Arizona/P` then it prints:

```
splitPath:  ['', u'United States', u'Arizona', u'P']

Peoria
Peoria
Phoenix
Peoria
Peoria
Peoria
Peoria
Phoenix
Phoenix
```